# printf with a variable on unix

Tags: bash, unix, printf, variable-assignment

I'm trying to use printf with a variable on unix (the output should be 10.1    ms) and so far I have:

```
var1=10.123 var2=mss printf "%.1f%4.2s\n" $var1 $var2
```

On one window of bash terminal, it is returning the line of text that I want, but on the other ones, it is returning 0.0, which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have used:

```
var1=10.123 var2=mss printf "%.1f%4.2s\n" $var1 $var2
```

just means: call `printf`  and put two variables into the environment of `printf` AND give the *actual* values of `$var1`  and `$var2` *as defined in the calling shell* as argument to `printf`. The reason is: not `printf` evaluates `$var1` and `$var2` but the calling shell.

So: If your shell's environment does not contain `var1`  and `var2` the call is equivalent to

```
var1=10.123 var2=mss printf "%.1f%4.2s\n"
```

If - on the other hand - the shell already knows these variables:

```
var1=foo
var2=bar
```

then the call is equivalent to:

```
var1=10.123 var2=mss printf "%.1f%4.2s\n" foo bar
```

So I assume you have set these variables to some value in this "one terminal".

Possible solution:

```
( var1=10.123; var2=mss; printf "%.1f%4.2s\n" $var1 $var2 )
```

**But:**

The variables would be visible only to `printf`. Therefore the simplest solution is to omit them completely:

```
printf "%.1f%4.2s\n" 10.123 mss
```

Comment: Better yet, just use whatever you're assigning to `var1` and `var2` before the command as the arguments to `printf`: `printf '%.1f%4.2s\n' 10.123 mss` There's no advantage to defining `var1` and `var2` here.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, I've adjusted the answer.